# What response code should we use on a REST reply when the response data is an error message

Tags: rest

We have a REST service where the response to a request may be an error message. A simple example is the request is a formula to calculate and the formula might have a divide by zero. In that case the response is an error code and error message.

So the communication with the REST service is all good. The service itself is responding to the request. But the response is an error message instead of the expected result.

In this case what is the best response code to use? 200 to say the entire communication process is good and we look in the returned JSON to determine if it’s an error? 500 to say it’s an error, but then look to see if we have the expected JSON to determine it was an error in the calculation? Some other code which says we are getting a response from the server but the response is an error message?

Comment: 50x sounds wrong if the calculation was the result of user input. None of the 40x codes seems suited, so I'd go with a plain 400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A simple example is the request is a formula to calculate and the formula might have a divide by zero. [...] In this case what is the best response code to use?

I would use **422 Unprocessable Entity**

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions. For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Don't rely *only* on HTTP code anyway, always add a description of the error in the body. I believe it's common practice to have all your endpoints reply with a JSON with `success` (true or false) and something like `error` (with the error message) if `success` if false, or `data` (with the result) if success is true.

Answer (score 0):

For error messages we can use 4XX Bad Request

Look at this post, for various status codes.

http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: I am pretty sure the OP is aware of those. But picking the right one for such a scenario is far from obvious.